# Entity Framework 4: ObjectContext event on successful save

Tags: entity-framework-4

Is there a good way to detect when the `ObjectContext` changes are actually committed?

`SavingChanges` occurs before going to the data store but I also need a way to know if those changes where actually committed.

Thanks in advance 
John

**Update:**

What I have is a code first DbContext. This is fed into dynamic data which as I discovered uses the DbContext's internal ObjectContext (to which I have access when casting to IObjectContextAdapter). The dbcontext's SaveChanges is not called, the objectcontext's SaveChanges is used instead. All I want to do is to be notified after the save is complete (i.e. event SavedChanges) so I can invalidate my cache.

Comment: If there is no exception those changes were commited.

Comment: I am not calling SaveChanges(). There is a bunch of possible callers of SaveChanges() so instead of going to all of them (if that is even possible) and editing them so I can be called after SaveChanges() I was hoping I would catch it in the DbContext.

Comment: Can't you connect to the event SavingChanges? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.savingchanges.aspx

Comment: That is fired before the data is comitted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no build-in event to handle this but you can override `SaveChanges` method in your derived context and fire any custom event specific to your own context type after you call `base.SaveChanges`.

Comment: That is true for the DbContext but in DynamicData the ObjectContext.SaveChanges() is called on which I have no control over (hence the ObjectContext request in the title of the question).

Comment: You can override `SaveChanges(SaveOptions)` for `ObjectContext` as well and Dynamic data accepts your derived `ObjectContext` so I don't see the difference.

Comment: I dont see how I can override anything in the ObjectContext. I am in the code first DbContext and the only way I have access to the ObjectContext is via ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.

Comment: What is your question? You are jumping from one topic to another all the time. You asked about `ObjectContext` you commented that my answer works only for `DbContext` and you're using Dynamic data with `ObjectContext` and now you are complaining back about `DbContext`. First step to get an answer is the ability to describe the problem - we don't see your code and we don't know what are you trying to do. Even your question tags don't describe technologies you are using.

Comment: True, its a bit vague I realize now. I should probably mark the answer as accepted and add a new question. What I have is a code first DbContext. This is fed into dynamic data which as I discovered uses the DbContext's internal ObjectContext (to which I have access when casting to IObjectContextAdapter). The dbcontext's SaveChanges is not called, the objectcontext's SaveChanges is used instead. All I want to do is to be notified after the save is complete (i.e. event SavedChanges) so I can invalidate my cache. Tell me if I should post another question.

Comment: Finally the question make sense. I have to say I never tried `DbContext` with Dynamic Data and I'm even surprised that it works. If it really works as you describe you will not achieve that unless you change your application to use `ObjectContext` globally. Dynamic data were created prior to DbContext API and they are supposed to use with ObjectContext API which offers much more functionality.

Comment: Yep I figured as much, but on a side note, since the ObjectContext exposes a SavingChanges event, doesnt it make sense for it to expose a SavedChanges event as well?

Answer (score 0):

pardon me, but I can't find the solution in the answer.

Let me rephrase this question according to my understanding (and my case):

I am using Dynamic Data, which ONLY accepts ObjectContext as configuration; if you use DbContext (which is the way to go with Code First) then you will have to pass the property "IObjectContextAdapater.ObjectContext" like the following:

```
DefaultModel.RegisterContext(() => { return ((IObjectContextAdapter) new MyDbContext()).ObjectContext; }, new ContextConfiguration() { ScaffoldAllTables = true });
```

The problem here is that when you save changes, the SaveChanges method of the MyDbContext is NOT called, instead Dynamic Data calls the method SaveChanges in the MyDbContext.ObjectContext. 
So overriding the SaveChanges in MyDbContext is useless in this case.

How can we access the SaveChanges in the ObjectContext property and change the behavior so we can write our custom code?

But anyway, the solution I found correct was in a comment by "rene" to the question above, which is adding an event handler for SavingChanges EVENT in the ObjectContext property, here is the link again:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.savingchanges.aspx

I hope this clears it