# Entity Framework 6 with dynamic data handle database exception override object context savechanges

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I would like to handle asp.net dynamic data database exceptions in EF6.

So I decided to achive this like example bellow (to show error on dynamic data page).

```
public partial class MyCustomDataContext : DbContext{
  public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        try
        { 
            base.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            throw ValidationException(null, "My message");
        }
}
```

The problem is that I when I click save in dynamic data I don't go to my overriden function. I found in net that dynamic data to save changes use DbContext's underlying ObjectContext.

So my question is how can I override that ObjectContext SaveChanges method to show user custom error message when I get UpdateExcetpion ?

Comment: [This might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688170/entity-framework-4-objectcontext-event-on-successful-save) TLDR: Does not seem like its possible to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

OK I have tested this and spoken to the Asp.Net team and the issue us that the EF DataSource actually still uses the ObjectContext by unwrapping the DbContext to get at the ObjectContext and therefor the SaveChanges override never get called what you need to do is:

```
public partial class NorthwindEntities : DbContext
{
    public NorthwindEntities()
        : base("name=DataModel")
    {
        ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.SavingChanges += ObjectContext_SavingChanges;
    }

    private void ObjectContext_SavingChanges(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

So in this SavingChanges event you will need to do things in the Objwect Context way.

For wrapping your errors you will need to use EF6.x and use the

[Logging and Intercepting Database Operations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/dn469464#BuildingBlocks.Interfaces)

Thanks to Rowan and Pranav from the EF and Asp.net Teams.